# Dell PowerEdge r710 figuring how to test my Power Connect 6224 Fiber Ports

Tags: windows-server-2008, dell-poweredge, fiber, dell-powerconnect

Hi i have been trying to figure out why i cannot view my power connect via fiber. I have connected it to my fiber card not sure what card it is at the moment but besides the point all im trying to do is get the server to detect the power connect. I'm fairly illiterate when it comes to sever Stuff etc. its just not my cup of tea not my but it is a need in this situation.
Can anyone please help me figure out what i need to do?! 
(I have not been able to find anything on the web that is useful to me.)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you've accidentally connected the Tx and Rx sides together; that is to say, a fiber connection needs to be crossed over when connected

```
Tx -> Rx
Rx -> Tx
```

The easiest way I've found to check this is to put a piece of thin paper over the fibre ports, then make sure the one with the shiny light goes into the one without said light.

Comment: "Do not stare into laser with remaining eye."

Comment: Eh, Multimode short range optics aren't *that* bright, IME.

Comment: I've forgotten to cross-over a fibre connector more times than I can remember.

Comment: One can never be too careful. :) But yes, agreed with LED-based optics. http://pantsnotfound.com/files/caution-laser-600.png

Comment: I did say to use a piece of paper.  I wonder if there's special tools for this.